# How to Handle overflowing elements in React-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to use flex in react-native to make any element inside `<View></View>` to arrange themselves when their length got bigger than their container's ?

Below is my code:

```
const FilmCasts = ({ artists }) => (
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', }}>
   {artists.map(artist => (
     <Image
       key={cast.name}
       source={{ uri: artist.img }}
       style={{ width: 80, height: 100 }}
    />
   ))}

</View>
);
```

This is what I want. I want to make the 5th and others to go below the first row automatically after they hit the screen width limit, like what HTML usually does

[image: This is what I want]

But instead, this is what I get when in React Native, the `<Image>` elements continue to be rendered outside their parent's width

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: try `flexWrap:'wrap'`

Comment: @AravindS works for me! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Awesome ! i will add it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the prop `flexWrap:'wrap'` for wrapping the elements. flexWrap controls whether children can wrap around after they hit the end of a flex container. More [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#flexwrap)

```
const FilmCasts = ({ artists }) => (
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',flexWrap:'wrap' }}>
   {artists.map(artist => (
     <Image
       key={cast.name}
       source={{ uri: artist.img }}
       style={{ width: 80, height: 100 }}
    />
   ))}

</View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply defined image with dynamically using the [Dimension](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) property of react native .

like when you are using

```
<Image
   resizeMode="cover" or try "contain"
   key={cast.name}
   source={{ uri: artist.img }}
   style={{ width: width * 0.5 , height: 100 }} // this will be done currently defining the values . 
/>
```

Here is one blog regarding image handling in react native [Click to see the blog](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-react-native-images-or-saying-goodbye-to-trial-and-error-b2baaf0a1a4d)

Hope my answer will give an idea to slove your problem

Comment: even though `flexWrap` property is the easiest way, but I think I will try your suggestion here, I want to make sure same UI experience across any device and display width

Comment: yes , both approach will work with width concepts . thanks